# Dictionary of European Languages

Tags: data-request, language, dictionary

I'm looking for a database that contains translations of words in different European languages (mainly Romance). The most important languages for my project are in order Latin, English, Spanish and French.

Here is an example of a format that would suit me perfectly.

```
lat;eng;esp;fra,...
domus,domo;house;casa;maison;...
```

Comment: Interesting question. This would work for languages with simple case structures, e.g. nouns, but verbs would be very tricky as they change with person

Comment: Taking the infinitive form should work.